# Have to fire click event twice to trigger full screen mode on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have a click event that calls the following code:

```
$('#video-overlay').on('click', '.media-thumb', function(e){
        $('.video-file')[0].play();
    $('.video-file')[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
    e.preventDefault();
    });
```

In my chrome browser this works fine but on ipad i have to click .media-thumb twice to actually get to fullscreen mode, testing on ipad2 v:iOS5. Can anyone offer some light on how I can resolve this so .play() and .webkitFullscreen() get called together?

Comment: Have you tried calling webkitEnterFullscreen() first and then play() ?

Comment: Do you have any hover-events on that element? On many devices with touchscreen the first click triggers the hover actions (since you can't hover there) and only on the second click the click-actions.

Comment: Hey yeah, tried that but get nothing when I run the code and no hover events either

Comment: if i place .webkitEnterFullScreen before .play() i get the error INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using touchstart?

```
$('#video-overlay').on('click touchstart', '.media-thumb', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.video-file')[0].play();
    $('.video-file')[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
});
```